# SwiftyJSON code - why/how does this work?

Tags: json, swift, swifty-json

I have been teaching myself how to parse JSON using SwiftyJSON and the fab PokeApi.co  I thought I was getting the hang of it, until I tried to get an array back of a Pokemon's different types.  The JSON returned looks like this:

```
...
        ],
        "base_experience": 155,
        "types": [
            {
                "slot": 2,
                "type": {
                    "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/3/",
                    "name": "flying"
                }
            },
            {
                "slot": 1,
                "type": {
                    "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/1/",
                    "name": "normal"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

I need to grab an array of the value for "name" within "types" and then "type".  I tried lots of different suggestions from here, the SwiftyJSON guide on their Github and various other sources, and the only thing I could get to work is this:

```
        let typesArray = json["types"].arrayValue.map({$0["type"]["name"].stringValue})
        for item in typesArray {
            self.currentPokemon.pokemonTypes.append(item.firstUppercased)
            print("Added \(item)")
        }
```

I am happy that I have got it to work, but I am desperately trying to get my head around parsing JSON and this just doesn't make sense to me!  Could anybody please explain to me what is going on? Is there a clearer/ more readable way of doing this?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Which bit of that code specifically don't your understand? You wrote it, you must understand some of it.

Comment: Sorry - I get everything other than the line: let typesArray = json["types"].arrayValue.map({$0["type"]["name"].stringValue})

Comment: Yeah, that's the important line. What specifically about that line? You wrote it, you must understand at least part of that line.

Comment: So I get that I am creating an array of the key "types". Does the second part drill down to get the values for the "name" key? What's with the $0 ?

Comment: Read about [Closures](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID94) in the Swift book.

Comment: Will do. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## JSON

First things first... I think you need to make sure you really understand JSON before you can wrap your head around what you are doing here. JSON objects are essentially a Key / Value object. The Key is a string and the value can be many things: array of more JSON objects, or even as simple as a string.

## Best Practices

So one thing I like to do when I have to parse through JSON for any response is create an enum of strings that will have all of the "Keys" in the json. Note that if you do not assign a calue to any case and the type is `String` when you do `pokemonApiParams.name.rawValue` it will automatically return the *stringified* version of your case!

```
enum pokemonApiParams: String {
    case baseExperience
    case types
    case slot
    case type
    case url
    case name
}
```

Now when you are working with your JSON you can use this enum to help make things clearer. This is especially nice if your API response ever changed a key. You could just change the enum value and everything would work! Another reason why this is a "best practice" is it takes out these "magic strings" from your code and keeps everything in one logistical place that you can refer to later!

```
// This would give you 155 in your example
json[pokemonApiParams.baseExperience.rawValue]
```

## Working through your example

Now to the part you were having trouble understanding.

First let's reconstruct your "types array" piece by piece...

```
let typesArray = json[pokemonApiParams.types.rawValue]
```

This guy creates a json object that contains the array of "types" in your response. Basic SwiftyJSON objects are great but you can be a little more specific here to get some more usage, hence why your example uses `.arrayValue`.

```
let typesArray = json[pokemonApiParams.types.rawValue].arrayValue
```

Now we have a JSON array object and we could go through it using various different looping functions. However you use the `.map` function next. This guy is super useful once you get used to it and use it some more!

### Understanding .map

Basically we can map each element in our array to be something else, in this case we are using a short hand to go through the array and get only the "name" attribute of each type. So we are mapping from a `[JSON] -> String`.

The $0 is the *shorthand* I was talking about. Imagine this as your index in a for loop. The map function will walk through the entirety of the array and $0 is the object in the array that is being looked at.

Check out the [map](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2908681-map) documentation too!

### Putting it all together

Looking at your response each *types* object has a *slot* and a *type*.

So back to your example (but using our enum!):

```
let typesArray = json[pokemonApiParams.types.rawValue].arrayValue
    .map {
        $0[pokemonApiParams.type][pokemonApiParams.name.rawValue].stringValue
    }
```

Now your typesArray is an array of strings. Another way to write this (which would be a little clearer and maybe easier to understand) is:

```
let typesArray = json[pokemonApiParams.types.rawValue].arrayValue
    .map { (types: JSON) -> String in
        types[pokemonApiParams.type.rawValue][pokemonApiParams.name.rawValue].stringValue
    }
```

This is clearer because we have to specify our object (types) instead of using the $0 shorthand and we specify what we are returning (String).

Hopefully this is all correct and clear!

Happy coding and go catch 'em all!

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much for making this a lot clearer.  I will definitely read up on the .map function as well as closures.  Super helpful explanation - hopefully it will help another noob like me in the future as well! Thanks again!